# HTML Content Not Centering on Narrow Screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, centering

I am using Bootstrap 3, and coding mainly for mobile websites. I am having trouble centering content when I don't want it to take up the whole line. When the screen is larger than a certain width, it doesn't get centered, & when it is smaller than that width (especially at the size we are optimizing it for), it won't even come away from the left border of the page. Also, some elements keep jumping in size when they get to be a certain size. I assume that last one is normal behavior, but can't for the life of me figure out why.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-11">
            <div class="col-xs-5 pull-left">
                <input type="text" class='form-control' id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right">
                <input type="text" class='form-control' id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class='form-control' id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
    </div>
</div>
```

The @media's in bootstrap-custom.css are:

```
@media (min-width 1200)
    .container {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
@media (min-width 992)
    .container {
        max-width: 940px;
    }
@media (min-width 768)
    .container {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if that's the right/accepted way to quote them.

I also have the rest of the bootstrap-custom.css, if you need that for your answer.

P.S. The whole reason I didn't have the first row (with firstName & lastName) take up the whole line is because I don't want it to. I wanted that row to be in the middle with space on either side.

P.P.S. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeRobot/AgSPe/).

Comment: it would be easier to understand if you put a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't done any Bootstrap before - I'm just stabbing in the dark.

> For a simple two column layout, create a `.row` and add the appropriate number of `.span*` columns. As this is a 12-column grid, each `.span*` spans a number of those 12 columns, and should always add up to 12 for each row (or the number of columns in the parent).

So, I changed your `col-xs-5` elements to `col-xs-6` so that they would add up to twelve, and therefore take up 100% of the row's width together. I moved your email input field into the `.container` and added the `col-xs-11` class in order for it to mirror the other `form-group`'s left and right margin. I wrapped your email input field in a `div` (as you had done with the other fields), and added the `col-xs-12` class to make it stretch to 100% of its parent row's width.

<strike>[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7T5/) is a fiddle.</strike>

> Also, some elements keep jumping in size when they get to be a certain
>   size. I assume that last one is normal behavior, but can't for the
>   life of me figure out why.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7T5/1/) is an *updated* fiddle that employs [CSS3 transitions](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS3%20transitions) to ease between your different `max-width`s.

Comment: I don't want them to take up their entire parents' rows. This is why I didn't add up to 12. I know that's not done, but I don't see another way besides adding extra empty elements with `visibility: hidden` or doing CSS's `width` with percents, which is what Bootstrap's `col-xs-*`'s are anyway. I tried that before, anyway, & it didn't work, either.

Comment: Try something _like_ [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7T5/3/). Adjust padding and column sizes where necessary. As nice as it is to avoid superfluous elements, a method doesn't come to mind for how you can `float` (`pull`) them as you desire, without a wrapper element... unless you fancy adding explicit `padding`s to position them the desired distances from the left/right.

Comment: I think you mean `margin`s, which I tried. `Padding` adds more space between the outside of the element & the actual element, while `margin` adds more space between elements. I know, it's confusing.

Comment: I meant `padding` - Bootstrap is using it to add spacing which pushes them _away_ from the center, which is what you didn't want. Regardless, which aspect of using `margin`/`padding` is not fulfilling your criteria? That would be what is referred to as "useful" information. I know, it's confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a way to say that without being infuriatingly patronizing. What is happening is, whenever I use `margin: auto`, the site looks fine on bigger screens (not quite centered, but whatever) but floats to the left on tiny screens, which is not what we want. I may have to try `margin` (or `padding`) with percents.

Comment: I'm a tad confused as to what the problem is. What's wrong with the example I provided? If you were to let me know then perhaps I could fix it. What's wrong with using the extra `div`s? The input fields **are** as close as they can get to the center given the current column arrangement. Either allow the columns to __fill__ the row and add padding/margin, or wait for `.col-xs-offset-*` to be implemented. If you don't wish to do that, then I cannot fathom what sort of solution you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is with smaller screens, which is what we are mainly making this site for. For some reason, either the `margin`s or `float`s in Bootstrap's classes or maybe HTML itself don't work as well on smaller screens (smartphones & maybe tablets). Also, 12 subdivisions (on Bootstrap's grid system) really isn't enough, but that's a whole other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried text-align:centre; to your container class?

Comment: try adding margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; to your content class so that all elements will align center horizontally.

Comment: That is what the Bootstrap class `container` does anyway. I also tried it by itself, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your markup a little. Wrap everything inside a `container` and make your `form-group` as rows..

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working demo: http://bootply.com/86294

P.S. - Take a look at Option #2 in the [demo](http://bootply.com/86294) so that your inputs don't get too small. This will allow them to stack vertically on the smallest screens.

Comment: How did you get the inputs to separate but still have them add up to 12?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by separate. Can you elaborate? Do you mean the firstname and lastname?

Comment: Yes. How did you get them to back away from each other? Whenever I do it in my code they bump up right next to each other.

Comment: Are you using the latest 3.0? They should work like the demo.

Comment: Yes, or else I couldn't use `col-xs-*`. Even when I paste it right in my code the lastName & firstName still bump up right next to each other. You think the jQuery version could have something to do with it?